# how to assign multiple values from to a value from another table in php/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

[this is my requirement_tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBnRy.jpg)

[and my documents_tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4153x.jpg)

and my expected result

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| doc_id | document_name | requirement_id |requirement_name | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
|   1    |Certifications |       3        | requirementname |
|        |               |       1        | requirementname |
|        |               |       7        | requirementname |
|        |               |       9        | requirementname |
|    2   |CAV            |       1        | requirementname |
|        |               |       4        | requirementname |
|        |               |       3        | requirementname |
|        |               |       5        | requirementname |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this output possible in displaying in HTML using PHP? Someone can show me how to?
Is this related to foreign keys and joining tables?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: Your question is beyond a simple 'answer' and more of you need a custom programmer.

Comment: @Aaron sir how is it possible can you show me how? or how to query those?

Comment: @user Can you show me your attempt?

Comment: If you have the ability to modify the design of this database, I would highly suggest you do so. You should be using 3 tables here (Requirements - JOIN - documents.

Comment: @Aaron sir, From the database I want to display it into the html as shown above. Do I have to join the tables. I know it's a one-to-many relationship but I don't know how to query those.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: FYI - your images appear to have reversed the "document" and "requirement" tables. (E.G. the label for each points to the other)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry @Cam ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be helpful to construct a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16d697/7) for questions such as these so that reviewers can follow along with a common schema/dataset. Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `document_id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `document_name` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_amount` INT(4),
  `requirement1` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement2` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement3` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement4` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement5` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement6` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement7` INT(11) DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE `requirement` (
  `requirement_id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `document_id` INT(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `requirement_name` VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

The main obstacle is that the requirements for each document are non-normalized; there may be as many as 7 different requirement options spread out across each of the document columns.  To allow for that, you'll need to bring them together into such a way that they represent a single column, which can be done via union:

```
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement1` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement2` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement3` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement4` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement5` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement6` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement7` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
```

Then you're able to join together your query into the desired result set:

```
SELECT d.document_id, d.document_name, r.requirement_id, r.requirement_name FROM
`document` as `d` JOIN
(
# correct for non-normalization via UNION on requirements
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement1` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement2` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement3` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement4` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement5` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement6` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
UNION
SELECT `document_id`, `requirement7` as 'requirement' FROM `document`
) `req`
ON d.document_id = req.document_id
JOIN `requirement` as `r`
ON req.requirement = r.requirement_id
WHERE req.requirement > 0
ORDER BY d.document_id, r.requirement_id;
```

Comment: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
It's the error it returns @Cam

Comment: thank you it actually worked. But what if I'll include the document_amount ?

Comment: @user simply add that field to your `SELECT` clause: `SELECT d.document_amount`.  The 'd' is simply an alias for the document table; such use of aliases is common in JOINs to make queries more readable.

Comment: Oh I see . So it combine queries. I get it now. But the thing is I got trouble in displaying it into HTML table do I have to copy the structure of the table it returns as a result in the sql in phpmyadmin? @Cam or just use a while loop?